Forward not-found (in specific directory) to a defined servlet path (for SPA using history.pushState)
Context
I have SPA application(s) using history.pushState() for navigation, so I need to serve the same HTML (possibly generated by JSP or servlet) for many URLs. There are static resources that must not be "intercepted/rewritten" by such mechanism though. I also need to add filters that will only match the HTML and not other static resources or other servlets. Finally, this "forwarding" can have to be scoped to a specific path (I have applications with multiple such SPAs, each with its own scope and HTML), and this is all using embedded Jetty.
I had working code with Jetty 9, 10, and 11, but Jetty 12 introduced breaking changes that makes it impossible to do. I'm looking for a way to replicate the same behavior with Jetty 12.
So, assuming those files:
/index.html
/subdir/
  +- app.js
  +- style.css
  `- index.html

and servlets mapped to /subdir/logout and /subdir/api/*.
I need that all those requests return the /subdir/index.html (properly going through filters with the request or forward dispatch type):

/subdir/
/subdir/index.html
/subdir/foo
/subdir/foo/bar
/subdir/bar

But those should properly return the static files or call the mapped servlets:

/subdir/app.js
/subdir/style.css
/subdir/api/foo
/subdir/logout

Working code with Jetty 9/10/11
With Jetty 9/10/11, I used to do it this way (note: context is a ServletContextHandler):
    // Sometimes I need a filter such as this one (injecting HTML/JS into the response)
    // or other filters that would redirect unauthenticated users to login (possibly SSO)
    context.addFilter(CsrfServletFilter.class, "*.html", EnumSet.of(REQUEST, ASYNC, FORWARD));
    // Sometimes the HTML is generated by a servlet (other times it would be an index.jsp file)
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(indexServlet), "/subdir/index.html");

    ServletHolder resources =
        new ServletHolder(
            "resources",
            new DefaultServlet(
                new ResourceService() {
                  @Override
                  protected void notFound(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                      throws IOException {
                    // For use with history.pushState: send back the index page for everything not found.
                    try {
                      response.setHeader("Content-Location", "/subdir/");
                      request.getRequestDispatcher("/subdir/").forward(request, response);
                    } catch (ServletException e) {
                      throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                  }
                }));
    resources.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");
    resources.setInitParameter("welcomeServlets", "exact");
    context.addServlet(resources, "/subdir/*");

Jetty 12 equivalent?
Jetty 12 changed much of the DefaultServlet API and internals such that the above is not possible anymore. What would be an alternative?

First, in Jetty 12 there is no such thing as a "notFound()" method on ResourceService, ResourceHandler, or DefaultServlet.
The technique you are using in Jetty 9/10/11:

doesn't handle conditional headers (as you have bypassed it with your code).
doesn't handle pre-compressed behavior (again, you have bypassed it)
doesn't handle etags (yep, you bypassed it)
the RequestDispatcher.forward() behavior will follow Servlet forwarding rules, and that means all kinds of things for your incoming request headers/attributes, and outgoing request headers/attributes (many are dropped, and some are overwritten per servlet spec).
shows a lack of understanding of the url-pattern matching rules and  order of the servlet spec.  The default pattern "/" is only used if no other url-pattern matching applies.  This means that your JSP files will be served by *.jsp url-pattern that is for JettyJspServlet. (see Servlet Spec: Use of URL Paths

Your implementation should have used the Servlet error-page handling on 404 instead.
<web-app 
   xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="6.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>static-alt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.example.AltStaticServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static-alt</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static-alt</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/static-alt</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");

ErrorPageErrorHandler errorPageErrorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
errorPageErrorHandler.addErrorPage(404, "/static-alt");
context.setErrorHandler(errorPageErrorHandler);

context.addServlet(AltStaticServlet.class, "/static-alt");

public class AltStaticServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if (req.getDispatcherType() == DispatcherType.ERROR)
        {
            if (handleError(req, resp))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        // simple 404 for requests that are not handled by this servlet
        resp.setStatus(404);
    }

    private boolean handleError(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String originalUri = (String)req.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI);
        if (originalUri.contains("/static/"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/static/");
            requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


I need that all those requests return the /subdir/index.html (properly going through filters with the request or forward dispatch type)

This is welcome-file logic on the servlet spec itself.
You can find that configurable in the WEB-INF/web.xml.
<web-app 
   xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="6.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });

But, based on what you have stated in your question, you don't need any of that complex DefaultServlet logic, at all.
Your code is basically a no-op in Jetty 9 / 10 / 11 and calls back to itself.  (In fact, in some cases, you have even created an infinite loop)
You need 2 things.

One or more properly defined Base Resources (for more than one, use a composite / combined resource).  Either specified in the ServletContextHandler or as a init-param on the DefaultServlet
The servlet spec normal DefaultServlet on the servlet named default.

Optionally, you can provide an additional DefaultServlet at a different Base Resource (via the init-params)
There are example of this found in the jetty-examples project.



Jetty
Path




Jetty 12
embedded/ee10-file-server


Jetty 11
embedded/file-server


Jetty 10
embedded/file-server


Jetty 9
embedded/file-server



Look at the ServletFileServerMultipleLocations examples.
If you choose to use the multiple Base Resource approach, you can simply use the resource combine features in Jetty 12.
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
ResourceFactory resourceFactory = ResourceFactory.of(context);

Resource defaultBase = resourceFactory.newClassLoaderResource("/webroot/");
Resource subdirBase = resourceFactory.newClassLoaderResource("/webroot/subdir/");
Resource multiBase = ResourceFactory.combine(defaultBase, subdirBase);

context.setBaseResource(multiBase);

ServletHolder holderDef = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
holderDef.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
context.addServlet(holderDef, "/");


Correct me if I'm wrong but this will never serve the subdir/index.jsp for a request to /subdir/foo, not would it work if the index page is actually generated by a servlet.

Since the DefaultServlet is on url-pattern of / it is only served if no other Servlet url-pattern matches it.  So that means your /subdir/index.jsp will be served by the Servlet JettyJspServlet on url-pattern *.jsp.  Yes the JSP will be handled by JSP before being served statically.
